# Distributed tensorflow monopolizes GPUs after running server.__init__

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two computers with two GPUs each. I am trying to start with distributed tensorflow and very confused about how it all works. On computer A I would like to have one `ps` tasks (I have the impression this should go on the CPU) and two `worker` tasks (one per GPU). And I would like to have two 'worker' tasks on computer B. Here's how I have tried to implement this, in `test.py`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--job_name',   required = True,            type = str)
parser.add_argument('--task_idx',   required = True,            type = int)
args, _    = parser.parse_known_args()
JOB_NAME   = args.job_name
TASK_INDEX = args.task_idx


ps_hosts     = ["computerB-i9:2222"]
worker_hosts = ["computerA-i7:2222", "computerA-i7:2223", "computerB-i9:2223", "computerB-i9:2224"]
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})
server  = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name = JOB_NAME, task_index = TASK_INDEX)

if JOB_NAME == "ps":
    server.join()
elif JOB_NAME == "worker":
    is_chief = (TASK_INDEX == 0)    

    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
            worker_device = "/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index, cluster = cluster)):

        a = tf.constant(8)
        b = tf.constant(9)

    with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
        sess.run(tf.multiply(a, b))
```

**What I am finding by running `python3 test.py --job_name ps == task_idx 0` on computer A, is that I see that both GPUs on computer A have immediately been reserved by the script and that computer B shows no activity.** This is not what I expected. I thought that since for the `ps` job I simply run `server.join()` that this should not use the GPU. However I can see by setting `pdb` break points that as soon as the server is initialized, the GPUs are taken. This leaves me with several questions:

**- Why does the server immediately take all the GPU capacity?
 - How am I supposed to allocate GPU and launch different processes?
 - Does my original plan even make sense? (I am still a little confused by tasks vs. clusters vs. servers etc...)**

I have watched the Tensorflow Developer Summit 2017 video on distributed Tensorflow and I have also been looking around on Github and blogs. I have not been able to find a working code example using the latest or even relatively recent distributed tensorflow functions. Likewise, I notice that many questions on Stack Overflow are not answered, so I have read related questions but not any that resolve my questions. I would appreciate any guidance or recommendations about other resources. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following will work when invoking from command line:

`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" python3 test.py --job_name ps --task_idx 0 --dir_name TEST`

Since I found this in a lot of code examples it seems like this may be the standard way to control an individual server's access to GPU resources.